# "Toast" a message via TimerTask

Tags: android, android-activity, toast, android-context

I found some info about how to access the context from the subclass and also some info about

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // Do something
  }
});
```

But in my case it does not work. The application is still running, but the activity is maybe already destroyed. The first (main) activity is the parent activity of the one where my TimerTask is created. My code:

```
TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // do something (cut)

    // and at the end show info
    getParent().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getParent(),
                  getResources().getString(R.string.st_toast_msg_stopped),
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    });
  }
};
curTimer.schedule(tt, millisecondsUntilStop);
```

There is no error/ exception at log. But the toasted message is not shown. :-(

Now I have no Idea what I can else do/ try. I hope someone of you can help me.

P.S.: Maybe I use the wrong context? But I tried also some other context like the Context of the current activity, the `ApplicationContext`, ... .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are using the wrong context here that is `getParent()`. Instead of using `getParent()` try to use the `current_Activity.this` like this,

```
TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // do something (cut)

    // and at the end show info
    Activity_name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(Activity_name.this,
                  getResources().getString(R.string.st_toast_msg_stopped),
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a TimerTask, why not user the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and set a [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) to fire off a broadcast? When you fire of the broadcast and catch it in your own BroadcastReciever that you've made, you'll have context in your BroadcastReciever with which to display your toast. Here's a quick high level example.

Where ever you're setting up your TimerTask in your activity, do this instead:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("yourBroadcastAction");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntenet.getBroadcast(this, 0, broadcastIntent, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, millisecondsUntilStop, broadcastIntent);
```

Then just create a BroadcastReciever that has a filter for the `yourBroadcastAction` and in the `onRecieve()` method do your toast like so:

```
public void onRecieve(Context context, Intent intent){
  Toast.makeText(context,
              getResources().getString(R.string.st_toast_msg_stopped),
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I'm sure this should work also! Thanks a lot!